# how to change state by setState in React hooks

Tags: reactjs, setstate

App.js

```
      <Route path="/detail/:id" >
        <PostDetail />
      </Route>
```

PostDetail.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios'


const PostDetail = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  let [comments, setComments] = useState([]);

  useEffect(async () => {
    await axios
      .all([
        axios.get(`https://dummyapi.io/data/v1/post/${id}`, {
          headers: { "app-id": process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY }
        }),
        axios.get(`https://dummyapi.io/data/v1/post/${id}/comment`, {
          headers: { "app-id": process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY }
        })
      ])
      .then(
        axios.spread((detail, comment) => {
          console.log("before: ", comments)
          console.log("data:", comment.data.data)
          setComments([...comment.data.data])
          console.log("after: ", comments)
        })
      )
      .catch((detail_err, comment_err) => {
        console.error(detail_err);
        console.error(comment_err);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      detail page:
    </div>
  );
};

export default PostDetail;
```

and got some data with axiosin useEffect hook, and used setComments() with the data(comment.data.data). but it doesn't set the axios data for some reason. What's wrong with it? If you help me out, it would be a huge help[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The setter method (`setComments`) is asynchronous. Therefore you cannot expect to get the updated value to log right after it.

```
setComments([...comment.data.data])
console.log("after: ", comments)
```

You should move the `log` to the component's top level.

```
const PostDetail = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  let [comments, setComments] = useState([]);

  useEffect(async () => {
    await axios
      .all([
        axios.get(`https://dummyapi.io/data/v1/post/${id}`, {
          headers: { "app-id": process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY }
        }),
        axios.get(`https://dummyapi.io/data/v1/post/${id}/comment`, {
          headers: { "app-id": process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY }
        })
      ])
      .then(
        axios.spread((detail, comment) => {
          console.log("before: ", comments)
          console.log("data:", comment.data.data)
          setComments([...comment.data.data])
        })
      )
      .catch((detail_err, comment_err) => {
        console.error(detail_err);
        console.error(comment_err);
      });
  }, []);

  // move the log to here 
  console.log("after: ", comments)

  return (
    <div>
      detail page:
    </div>
  );
};

export default PostDetail;
```

If you want to do some other work when `comments` gets changed, add a `useEffect` hook with `comments` as a dependancy.

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(comments);
}, [comments]);
```

Comment: I see, Thank you so much! i need another question, if the console you moved  is there, async and await are neccessary?

Comment: there is no connection between async-await and moving the log. react invoke the  PostDetail when any state of the component changes. That's why I asked to move the log. The way you have used async-await is not needed as you used then block to get the changes. You can remove async-await really.

Comment: thank you! I posted another issue. Could you help me out again...? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71368340/how-to-wait-for-setstate-in-useeffect-until-render