# How to wait for setState in useEffect until render?

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

```
  let [item, setItem] = useState({});
  let [comments, setComments] = useState([]);
  useEffect(async () => {
    await axios
      .all([
        axios.get(`https://dummyapi.io/data/v1/post/${id}`, {
          headers: { "app-id": process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY }
        }),
        axios.get(`https://dummyapi.io/data/v1/post/${id}/comment`, {
          headers: { "app-id": process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY }
        })
      ])
      .then(
        axios.spread((detail, comment) => {
          setItem({ ...detail.data })
          setComments([...comment.data.data])
        })
      )
      .catch((detail_err, comment_err) => {
        console.error(detail_err);
        console.error(comment_err);
      });
  }, []);
```

i setStated like above.
and I was trying to use the State in return(), but it seems it didn't wait for the data set.

```
return (
          <div>
            {item.tags.map((tag, index) => {
              return <Chip label={tag} key={index} />
            })}
          </div>
)
```

because i got an error message like this : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map').
Since i initialized 'item' just empty {object}, so it can't read 'item.tags', which is set by setState in useEffect.

How can i wait for the data set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In generic, it would set a state `isFetched` to determine if the data from api   is ready or not. And when the `isFetched` equal to `true`, it means the `item.tags` have value.

```
const [isFetched, setIsFetched] = useState(false);
useEffect(async () => {
  await axios.all(...).then(() => {
    ...
    ...
    setIsFetched(true);
  })
}, [])

// You could return null or an Loader component meaning the api is not ready
if (!isFetched) return null;
return (
      <div>
        {item.tags.map((tag, index) => {
          return <Chip label={tag} key={index} />
        })}
      </div>
)
```

On the other hand, you could use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to avoid using `map` from an `undefined` value (that is `item.tags`), the right way is replace `item.tags.map` to `item.tags?.map`.

Answer (score 2):

```
let [item, setItem] = useState({});
```

Your initial state is an empty object, and there will always be at least one render that uses this initial state. Your code thus needs to be able to work correctly when it has this state. For example, you could check if item.tags exists before you try to use it:

```
if (item.tags) {
  return (
    <div>
      {item.tags.map((tag, index) => {
        return <Chip label={tag} key={index] />
      })}
    </div>
  );
} else {
  return <div>Loading...</div>
}
```

Alternatively, you could change your initial state so it has the same shape that it will have once loading has finished:

```
let [item, setItem] = useState({ tags: [] });
```

Answer (score 2):

Initially, `item` is an empty JSON (`{}`). You should be using the [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)(`?.`) to easily get rid of the null or undefined exceptions.

```
return (
          <div>
            {item?.tags?.map((tag, index) => {
              return <Chip label={tag} key={index} />
            })}
          </div>
)
```