# How do I change an url inside a context on component mount?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, axios, react-context

I'm trying to use a context to mount all videos in home page and reuse it to mount only the filtered videos in the search page using youtube API.
This is my context:

```js
import { createContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { IVideo } from "../@types/video";
import axios from "axios";
import moment from "moment";
import { IContextProps, IVideoContext } from "../@types/context";

export const VideoContext = createContext<IVideoContext>({} as IVideoContext);

export const VideoData = ({ children }: IContextProps) => {
  const [videos, setVideos] = useState<IVideo[]>([]); // the videos state is coming out as undefined
  const [url, setUrl] = useState(``) // the url state shows the right url on a console.log
  const [dependency, setDependency] = useState(``) // this state also has the right value in it
  
 useEffect(() => { 
       load() // for some reason this seems to not be working
   }, [dependency])
 
  async function load() {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(url) // this code works if I put the url manually here
      setVideos(response.data.items)
    }catch(error){
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
  
  function formatViewCount(viewCount: number): string {
    if (viewCount >= 1000000) {
      return `${(viewCount / 1000000).toFixed(0)} mi de visualizações`;
    } else if (viewCount >= 1000) {
      return `${(viewCount / 1000).toFixed(0)} mil visualizações`;
    } else {
      return `${viewCount} visualizações`;
    }
  }

  function getPublishedTime(publishedAt: string) {
    const now = moment();
    const publishedTime = moment(publishedAt);
    const diffDays = now.diff(publishedTime, 'days');

    if (diffDays <= 0) {
      return 'hoje';
    } else if (diffDays === 1) {
      return 'há 1 dia';
    } else if (diffDays <= 7) {
      return `há ${diffDays} dias`;
    } else if (diffDays <= 30) {
      const diffWeeks = Math.floor(diffDays / 7);
      if (diffWeeks === 1) {
        return 'há 1 semana';
      } else {
        return `há ${diffWeeks} semanas`;
      }
    } else if (diffDays <= 365) {
      const diffMonths = Math.floor(diffDays / 30);
      if (diffMonths === 1) {
        return 'há 1 mês';
      } else {
        return `há ${diffMonths} meses`;
      }
    } else {
      const diffYears = Math.floor(diffDays / 365);
      if (diffYears === 1) {
        return 'há 1 ano';
      } else {
        return `há ${diffYears} anos`;
      }
    }
  }
  
    return (
        <VideoContext.Provider value={{ videos, getPublishedTime, formatViewCount, setUrl, setDependency }}>
            {children}
        </VideoContext.Provider>

    )
}
```

This is my home page code:

```js
import { useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import VideoComponent from "../../components/videoComponent";
import { Container } from "./styles";
import { VideoContext } from "../../context/videoContext";
import { IVideo } from "../../@types/video";
import { useCategoryContext } from "../../context/categoriesContext";

function Home(){

    const {categoryId} = useCategoryContext()
    const { videos, setUrl, setDependency } = useContext(VideoContext)
    const API_KEY = 'AIzaSyBgyeOAGzLblKVCjEI-soVVLkQdNfvApkA'

    useEffect(() => {
        setUrl(`https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&part=statistics&chart=mostPopular&maxResults=48&videoCategoryId=${categoryId}&key=${API_KEY}`);
        setDependency(categoryId)
    }, [])

    return (
        <Container>
            {videos.map((video: IVideo) => (
                <VideoComponent video={video} key={video.id} />
            ))}
        </Container>
    )
}

export default Home;
```

The idea is that when the home component mount it sets the url to the context which gets the videos from the API. Trying to make it work cause I want to use the same process in the search page with a diferent url without repeating all that code.

With this code I`m getting an unidentified object in the video state.

```js
import { useContext } from "react";
import { IVideos } from "../../@types/video";
import { ChannelImage, Container, ImageBanner, TextCard, TextContainer, Title, TitleContainer } from "./styles";
import { VideoContext } from "../../context/videoContext";

function VideoComponent({video}:IVideos){
   
  const { formatViewCount, getPublishedTime } = useContext(VideoContext)

    return (
      <Container>
        <ImageBanner src={video.snippet.thumbnails.maxres?.url || video.snippet.thumbnails.high?.url} />
        <TitleContainer>
          <ChannelImage>{video.snippet.channelTitle.charAt(0).toUpperCase()}</ChannelImage>
          <TextContainer>
            <Title>{video.snippet.title}</Title>
            <TextCard>{video.snippet.channelTitle}</TextCard>
            <TextCard>{`${formatViewCount(Number(video.statistics.viewCount))} - ${getPublishedTime(video.snippet.publishedAt)}`}</TextCard>
          </TextContainer>
        </TitleContainer>
      </Container>
    )
}

export default VideoComponent;
```

This is the video card to be mounted in home page just in case (it worked fine when the all the code in the context was in home page without trying to set the url through states)

Please help me find where the mistake is.

Comment: It's hard to understand what the problem you are having is. Which line has what specific error?

Comment: Will try editing later, but I get an error of "can't map undefined" on the videos.map line in home page. A comand.log on the url state gives me the right url, on dependency state gives me the right number, but on videos state which is being mapped returns undefined... makes me believe the load() function on the useEffect of the context isn't working for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Continued searching until I found the answer here:

[How to wait for setState in useEffect until render?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71368340/how-to-wait-for-setstate-in-useeffect-until-render)

Just made a conditional chaining on the home page (changed videos.map to videos?.map).

axios just wasn't waiting for the setUrl in the context.

Sorry for the trouble of a badly written question.